# How can the fluid stream be stuck to the top of flask?

Tags: unity, monodevelop

I created a flask and added a fluid stream to the top of the flask. When I translate the flask, the fluid stream goes along with the top of the flask. How do I achieve this when rotation occurs.

```
   void Start () {
    aa.transform.position = new Vector3(bb.transform.position.x, 
    bb.transform.position.y + 4, bb.transform.position.z);
    aa.SetActive(false);
    aa.SetActive(true);
   }



void Update () {
    aa.transform.position = new Vector3(bb.transform.position.x, bb.transform.position.y+4, bb.transform.position.z);
   //aa is the fluid stream and bb is the flask
    cc.transform.position = new Vector3(bb.transform.position.x, bb.transform.position.y + 4, bb.transform.position.z);
    }
```

[image: The traslation works. But you can see the gap between top of flask and rotation here. How do I close that gap?]

The traslation works. But you can see the gap between top of flask and rotation here. How do I close that gap?

Answer (score 1):

```
// The flask we want to attach to.
public Transform flask;

// The stream object (assuming the liquid flows from its local origin)
public Transform stream;

// Position of the spout in the flask's local space.
public Vector3 spout;

// By running in LateUpdate, we ensure the flask has had a chance to move 
// already this frame, before we try to follow it.
void LateUpdate() {
    // Set our stream's origin to the position of the spout after applying
    // the flask's transformation (including translation, rotation, and scale).
    stream.transform.position = flask.TransformPoint(spout);
}
```